# Derive Date from first non NaN entry in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to pandas and python and am facing a big problem now. I have a dataframe that consists of payments that have been made in specific months in specific years for certain customers.

| Customer | A | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Year of payment | 2020 | 2021 | 2021 | 2020 |
| january | NaN | 14 | NaN | NaN |
| february | NaN | 20 | 30 | NaN |
| march | 20 | NaN | 30 | NaN |
| etc | NaN | 5 | 30 | NaN |

Sometimes there are several years listed per customer (as for customer A), sometimes not. Sometimes there are only NaN-values in a specific year.

I need to find out when the first payment for every customer has been made. The result should look like this then.

| Customer | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first payment | march 2020 | february 2021 | - |

I have been trying to solve this problem extensively for several hours yesterday but didn't even get close to finding a solution. It would be amazing if someone could point me in the right direction:)

edit: here are the details on the dataframe:

Index(['January__c', 'February__c', 'March__c', 'April__c', 'May__c',
'June__c', 'July__c', 'August__c', 'September__c', 'October__c',
'November__c', 'December__c'],
dtype='object')
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 7369 entries, ('a1k06000004DjDdAAK', '2021') to ('a1k1o000006NRP4AAO', '2021.0')

Data columns (total 12 columns):

| # | Column | Non-Null Count | Dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | January__c | 1810 non-null | float64 |
| 1 | February__c | 2207 non-null | float64 |
| 2 | March__c | 2614 non-null | float64 |
| 3 | April__c | 2991 non-null | float64 |
| 4 | May__c | 3328 non-null | float64 |
| 5 | June__c | 3789 non-null | float64 |
| 6 | July__c | 4208 non-null | float64 |
| 7 | August__c | 4583 non-null | float64 |
| 8 | September__c | 4757 non-null | float64 |
| 9 | October__c | 2515 non-null | float64 |
| 10 | November__c | 1345 non-null | float64 |
| 11 | December__c | 2193 non-null | float64 |

dtypes: float64(12)
memory usage: 879.9+ KB
None

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: And what is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: You will find data analysis easier when your data is in *tidy data format* https://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape, convert months with years to `DatetimeIndex`, reshape for remove `NaN`s rows and get minimal datetimes per `Customer`:

```
d = {('A', '2020'): {'january__c': np.nan, 'february__c': np.nan, 'march__c': 20.0}, 
     ('A', '2021'): {'january__c': 14.0, 'february__c': 20.0, 'march__c': np.nan}, 
     ('B', '2021'): {'january__c': np.nan, 'february__c': 30.0, 'march__c': 30.0}, 
     ('C', '2020'): {'january__c': np.nan, 'february__c': np.nan, 'march__c': np.nan}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).rename_axis(['Customer','Year of payment'], axis=1)

print (df)
Customer            A           B    C
Year of payment  2020  2021  2021 2020
january__c        NaN  14.0   NaN  NaN
february__c       NaN  20.0  30.0  NaN
march__c         20.0   NaN  30.0  NaN
```

---

```
df = df.stack()
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1]}'), format='%B__c %Y')

s = (df.stack()
       .reset_index()
       .groupby('Customer')['level_0'].min()
       .dt.strftime('%B %Y')
       .reindex(df.columns.unique()))

df = s.rename('first payment').to_frame().T
print (df)
Customer                A              B    C
first payment  March 2020  February 2021  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! unfortunately I did not get it to work yesterday. It returns the error 'ValueError: time data 'Customer 0' does not match format '%B %Y' (match)'.

Comment: @sonnen_flo - can you test `format='%B__c %Y')` ?

Comment: no it does not work. I think the problem might be that the lambda function does not point to the right string. df.stack() returns the following:                        Customer  0       A
                 1       B                                                                                                                        
                 2       C
                 3       D
             
                           ...        
december    6993                353.03
            6995                 23.47
            7001                119.07

Comment: @sonnen_flo - Added sample data like in question, for me working nice. If error  `'ValueError: time data 'Customer 0' does not match format '%B %Y' (match)'` it means format of months is different like `january__c`, `february__c` ...

Comment: yes your example works, thank you. But for my data it does not work, unfortunately. I think it has to do with the formating of the dataframe. I found out, that I didn't have the indexes assigned right, which I now have.  df.columns and df.index returns the very same results as in the example. but now, when I use stack(), the error returns 'cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'

Comment: @sonnen_flo - It means there is some duplicates. Check it by `print (df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)])

print (df.loc[:, df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])`

Comment: @sonnen_flo - first test rows, so 0 rows, second tested columns

Comment: yes I found the duplicates and removed them. I can stack the dataset now. The only problem I run into now is that the years are sometimes in the format 2021.0 and sometimes only 2021. This is why they cannot be converted to a date.